# Maven war contain two war inside

Tags: java, maven

I would like to have a final war package that contains two packages of war:

Frontend - angularjs,
BackendApi - including REST to the next (outside api)

I realize that I can pack it in ear, but I care about the war

```
<modules>
    <module>Commons</module> <!-- jar package -->
    <module>WarCreator</module> <!-- war package -->
    <module>Web/Frontend</module> <!-- war package -->
    <module>Web/BackendApi</module> <!-- war package -->
</modules>
```

WarCreator builds the entire package in war, pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>testtest</artifactId>
        <groupId>testtest</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <artifactId>Dist</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>testtest</groupId>
            <artifactId>Frontend</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>testtest</groupId>
            <artifactId>BackendApi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Both Backend and FrontendApi packages have jboss-web.xml files, with the following settings:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/rest</context-root>
</jboss-web>


<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/view</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

but the final war pack has only the first module and only this one is registered (visible in the widlfly logs).

Is there a way to get a war containing two packages of war?

Comment: And what are you going to do with that war? You wont be able to deploy it to web container like that.

Comment: first war contains spring application with strong spring-security; second war is access free, without validate

Comment: I have a feeling you just need to combine both wars into an archive. If that's the case then dont use war but instead use zip or tar archive using maven assembly plugin and change your WarCreator pom type to just `pom`.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you see that you could package two wars in a war ?
A war is not designed to contain another war.

Maven will not allow to do it naturally as you noticed.
And even if you manage to do that by using a trick, the application server will probably not recognize them.
To achieve what you want, use rather a EAR that is the conventional way to package multiple wars or better : don't try to correlate them.
Indeed, make the WARs independent provides much more flexibility for their deployment and maintenance.

Comment: first war contains spring application with strong spring-security; second war is access free, without validate

Comment: Sharing can also being done via EAR...no need to be container specific...

Comment: @LLL RRR And it is fine.

Comment: @khmarbaise Adding all in the EAR is the first way I propose. Sincerely, I did it several years ago but I have some difficulties to go into this way today. EAR is specific container (Java EE Server only) and creates a strong coupling between the WARs for their build and their deployment/undeployment. Independent WARs prevents from getting monolithic applications. I removed the part about sharing classes as it is also a bad practice. An application should be designed to be the more autonomous possible even on a Java EE Server. Today you are on JBoss, tomorrow you can target another server.